# How did Baymax transfer Tadashi's memory card?

Tags: big-hero-6

The following contains spoilers from *[Big Hero 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Hero_6_%28film%29)* (film).

> When Baymax saves Hiro and the pod by using his rocket arm at the cost of getting left behind, he somehow got Tadashi's memory card transferred to his rocket arm. [image]

How did he do that without going berserk kungfu mode?

Comment: We didn't see what happened post arm-expulsion, so Baymax *might* have gone berserk. Plus his battery was running very low, the hand-propulsion might have been his last action.

Comment: @Mooz, we did see Baymax post-arm expulsion. Check edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that Baymax doesn't need the discs to *function*, they appear to simply be backups with various information on them that's not part of his core programming, in this case 'health care data' on the green disc and 'karate data' on the red disc.

When Hiro removes Baymax' health care disc (before attacking the professor), Baymax says

> "Hiro, this is not what...."

**before his disc is reinserted**. This shows that he can quite happily speak and move without *either* of the discs in place.

[image]

---

It stands to reason that Baymax simply copied his personality and experiences over to the green disc when Hiro wasn't looking and also presumably discarded the red disc at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

In universe answer: Because seeing his vulnerability, Baymax had used the very reasonable countermeasure of copying the contents of each memory chip to each other, thus achieving redundancy.

Out of universe answer: Because, sigh, Disney needed a last minute drama sequence to jerk your tears. To be honest I was wondering in that entire scene why Baymax didn't just tell Hiro to take his memory chips, and thus spare the kid a lot of unnecessary trauma. But hey, I guess pretending to die is a well known healthcare technique in Japamerica.

Comment: Do you have canon quotes or lines to explain the in-universe answer?

Comment: No. It isn't actually explained. However, given that Baymax said "I'll add that to my library of medical procedures" to the fist bump thing, his memory chip was writable and Baymax had access permissions - and I'd assume Hiro's new chip is no different. Thus, it would be trivial for him to copy files from one to the other and that's what I would do in his position.

Comment: Speculation isn't exactly an answer. :D

Comment: Also if Tadashi was *really* a genius, there ought to be a github repo out there with full version controlled backups of every Baymax iteration! Keep backups, grad students!

Comment: And Baymax should sync himself periodically to the Cloud via a built into 4G connection! Just what is the Professor teaching these kids?

Comment: There is no evidence at all in the film to support this answer.